# Format UserForm object by a macro and preserve formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I use a macro to position and resize dozens of already existing `UserForm` elements, mainly `CommandButton` objects, through `UserForm_Initialize` / `UserForm_Activate` events.

The problem is that these events only temporarily change layout and formatting for pop-up window:

[image]

and have no effect on object itself:

[image]

I would like to change formatting and positioning on `UserForm` object, so that I can make additions while actually seeing the layout which macro currently presents to user. Is it even possible?

Comment: `The problem is that these events only temporarily change layout and formatting for pop-up window and have no effect on object itself.` - Can you please explain this a bit more? Which pop-up window? And what affect on which object are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: I meant pop-up window which appears on screen from `UserForm_Initialize` / `UserForm_Activate` and presents `UserForm` formatted through my code. I would like the formatting to be applied to the underlying `UserForm` for good. With buttons not resized and not positioned properly it looks like a mess when I open the object and I would not like to do so many changes manually each time I change concept of the layout.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why not just create the userform in the VBE? Why do it programmatically? If you need it to "stick" I guess that means that you want it to stay the same for the next time you open the form? Are you asking for like a session state to be persisted between userform activation? Even between workbook close/opens?

Comment: You can it add in Workbook.open

Comment: I have attached screenshots to my question, hopefully it will make my goal more clear. To put it simple: I want things on 2nd screenshot to look like on the 1st screenshot without recreating everything manually.

Comment: Are you asking about "design time" modifications?  Something like this maybe?  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/3/3/vba-code-to-create-modify-delete-userforms

Comment: @TimWilliams It's exactly what I meant! `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ExcelDatePicker").Designer` allows me to modify all controls in VBE view. However, I'm getting an error on the following: `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ExcelDatePicker").Properties("Caption") = "test"` - method `Properties` failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim myUserform As Object

    Set myUserform = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ExcelDatePicker")


    With myUserform
        .Activate '< added from link below
        .Properties("Caption") = "Testing"
        .Properties("Width") = 200
        .Properties("Height") = 200
    End With

End Sub
```

Caption is a property of the `UserForm`, not its `Designer`

**EDIT** - update from OP:
Finally I received an answer on how to fix these problems: 
[UserForm error: Method 'Properties' of object '_VBComponent' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582890/userform-error-method-properties-of-object-vbcomponent-failed/52935900#52935900)

Comment: Yes, I didn't use `Designer` for `Properties` in my previous comment. I actually narrowed down the problem when running Your code from a module - it works for me when I run it 1 time and on 2nd run it fails with an error on line with `Properties`.

Comment: Yes I mis-read your comment re `Designer` I can run my code multiple times without any error though: I don't know what's gong on in your case...  Maybe you could edit your question to include your current code?

Comment: Actually I haven't described what exactly caused an issue, but I was able to catch the problem: running your code normally and then with changed Width or Height parameters triggers an error, but as early as on Caption line and to be honest, it's hard for me to find exact pattern, as sometimes change will not trigger error and sometimes opening file and running macro with existing value will trigger it.

Comment: Finally I received an answer on how to fix these problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582890/userform-error-method-properties-of-object-vbcomponent-failed/52935900#52935900 If you mention the '.Activate' as a remedy to possible errors from using this method in Your answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: It's what I did for another question which was entirely about errors I'm receiving, but in this one You provided correct solution, which only sometimes resulted in VBA errors and possibly not on everyone's machine. `.Activate` is only an addition which will make operating on `Designer` stable.