# UserForm error: Method 'Properties' of object '_VBComponent' failed

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to edit my UserForm object in VBE with code.

When I use the following, I get an error as in post title:

```
Sub myTest()
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Properties("Caption") = "myCaption"
End Sub
```

I tried changing "Caption" to "caption", the same error. Also this error happens when I try to set `Width` or `Height` properties, not always at first time, but when I run the code again to resize.

Edit 1:
"Trust access to the VBA project object model" in macro settings is enabled.

Edit 2:
Error does not happen when new workbook and UserForm are created. It does happen when UserForm is recreated in workbook in which an error already happened.

Edit 3:
Adding `Unload UserForm1` or `Set UserForm1 = Nothing` before doesn't help.

Edit 4:
For new workbook, if I create UserForm and run this code from a module, but after right clicking on UserForm -> View Object, then I get an error: "Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus." When I confirm, on consecutive macro runs I'm getting an error as in post title.

Edit 5:
The same happens on Excel 2010 and 2016.

Comment: `UserForm1.Caption = "myCaption"`

Comment: Items in `VBComponents` collection don't support `.Caption`.

Comment: What i mean is, if all you want to do is change the caption then why not do it like in my first comment? why even go through VBproject object in the first place?

Comment: @Banana Because it will change caption only on UserForm displayed for user through `UserForm_Activate()` or `UserForm_Initialize()`. I want to change caption for an object in VBE.

Comment: i see, well i tested your code and it works fine. the only thing i can think of is permissions to access VBProject. you have to grant VBA permission to edit the VBProject programatically in your excel settings under Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> Trust access to the VBA project object model

Comment: I have this checked. I work on Excel 2010.

Comment: In that case maybe you have conflicting libraries loaded, did you try to close all excel files and try the code on a clean new document with only one UserForm?

Comment: That's what I just tested when you mentioned that it works on your end. I was able to successfully run this code multiple times on fresh workbook with fresh UserForm. I will also test changing `Height` and `Width` and post an update.

Comment: You'd get that error if the form is currently loaded.

Comment: I updated my original post

Comment: change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` in addition to unloading the userform.

Comment: @Banana Using `ActiveWorkbook` still doesn't work. Actually I have just noticed that `Unload UserForm1` makes an error appear even on 1st run on new workbook with new UserForm, so it does the things "worse".

Comment: i can confirm that using unload actually fixes the errors in all my runs. try reopening your workbook and running a sub with 3 lines of code `UserForm1.Show` , `Unload UserForm1` , `ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Properties("Caption") = "myCaption"`

Comment: Unfortunately no change on my end as showing `UserForm1` did not help (also I had to X button click to close it). Which Excel version do you use? I can test it on 2016 later.

Comment: at the moment i can only test it on 2013, will get my hands on 2016 in a few hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172009/discussion-between-banana-and-ryszard-jedraszyk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May simply try this

```
Sub myTest()
 ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Activate
 ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Properties("Caption") = "myCaption"
End Sub
```

It is working in Excel 2007 and expect to work in any version.
May Please refer my Answer to Post **[After Import of a Userform into VBComponents Properties cannot be read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703642/after-import-of-a-userform-into-vbcomponents-properties-cannot-be-read/52881988#52881988)**

Comment: Thank You Ahmed! Worked for me on 2010. It looks like it's one of these rare cases where `.Activate` needs to be used, but as it's only for development and fired once in a while, this clunkiness isn't a problem at all. Most important - it works and is reliable.

Comment: With my installation of Excel (2016), VBA stops execution after `.activate()` has been called.